# Creating a Tombstone in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have some values in TypeScript that are only needed within the type system. I'm looking for a way to void the values without forgetting their type. The function `bury` in the example below is expected to replace the runtime value with undefined and cast it into a tombstone for the buried type. However, my example implementation of `Tombstone` is not sufficient because `Tombstone<{ id: string }>` equals `void` which equals `Tombstone<{ id: number }>`. What would be a good way to distinguish between buried values? I'd like to avoid confusing developers and wasting runtime memory with values that are only needed for type checking.

```js
type Tombstone<_A> = void
function bury<A>(_value: A): Tombstone<A> {
  return undefined as Tombstone<A>
}

type Item = { id: number }

const correct: Tombstone<Item> = bury({ id: 123 })
const incorrect: Tombstone<Item> = bury({ id: 'abc' })  // <- should not work

type Special = Item & { meta: string }

const correct2: Tombstone<Item> = bury({ id: 123, meta: 'test' })
const correct3: Tombstone<Special> = bury({ id: 123, meta: 'test' })

const incorrect2: Tombstone<Special> = bury({ id: 123 })  // <- should not work
```

Comment: If `interface SpecialItem extends Item { special: true }`, do you want to be able to assign a `Tombstone<SpecialItem>` value to a variable of type `Tombstone<Item>`?  If not, why not?  I'm trying to understand if `Tombstone<T>` should be covariant in `T` or invariant in `T`.

Comment: @jcalz excellent feedback! I updated the question with more comprehensive examples.

Comment: I'm starting to think that name `Sighting` would be more appropriate since the original value might still be in use somewhere without us knowing. Thus calling `bury` doesn't really terminate the value.

Answer (score 1):

Using a class with a private property seems to work.

```
class Tombstone<A> {
  // @ts-ignore _a is used to store the type and is never read
  private readonly _a!: A
}

function bury<A>(_value: A): Tombstone<A> {
  return undefined as unknown as Tombstone<A>
}

type Item = { id: number }

const correct: Tombstone<Item> = bury({ id: 123 })
// @ts-expect-error string is not assignable to number
const incorrect: Tombstone<Item> = bury({ id: 'abc' })

type Special = Item & { meta: string }

const correct2: Tombstone<Item> = bury({ id: 123, meta: 'test' })
const correct3: Tombstone<Special> = bury({ id: 123, meta: 'test' })
// @ts-expect-error missing required property 'meta'
const incorrect2: Tombstone<Special> = bury({ id: 123 })
```